# MySQL '/' in column name

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

The problem is that I need to construct the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT c.Animal/Dog, c.Animal/Cat, b.Ecoli
FROM Creatures AS c, Bacteria AS b
WHERE blablabla;
```

Result:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c.Animal' in 'field list'
```

Before people start to tell me that I should rename the columns, it's not my database. I can't change anything, I just need to get this query to work (if at all possible).

Comment: How about quotes i.e. \`table.columnName\`

Comment: I tried \`table.Column\`, table.\`Column\`, 'table.Column', table.'Column', so thats with single quotes and back ticks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT `c.Animal/Dog`, `c.Animal/Cat` b.Ecoli
FROM Creatures AS c, Bacteria AS b
WHERE blablabla;
```

**EDIT:**

Try once by not using Aliases.

```
SELECT `CREATURES`.`ANIMAL/DOG`, `CREATURES`.`ANIMAL/CAT`, `BACTERIA`.`ECOLI` FROM CREATURES, BACTERIA WHERE blablabla;
```

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c.Animal/Dog' in 'field list'

Comment: i made a tiny mistake. The backticks did work, i just needed to do it like: c.`Animal/Dog`. I thought i tried that properly, but i made a mistake there. THNX ALOT!

Comment: Glad it worked. I hope you meant c.` `Animal/Dog` ` (without the spaces of course). I can't get to escape the backticks properly in comments.

Comment: That's exactly what i meant c.\`Animal/Dog\`